Using the cell attribute of Tanstack v8 with Server Side rendering in NextJS
When I use the cell attribute in the columns definition and try to import it into a Server Side Component, I get this error:
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
  {accessorKey: ..., header: "Status", cell: function cell}

These are my columns:
export const columns: ColumnDef<Task>[] = [
    {
        accessorKey: "task_status",
        header: "Status",
        cell: props => {
            const taskStatus : TaskStatus = props.row.getValue("task_status")
            return (
                <Badge className={"cursor-pointer w-full"} customColor={taskStatus.color_task_status}>
                    {taskStatus.name_task_status}
                </Badge>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "name_task",
        header: "Task",
        cell: props => {
            return <span className={"block max-w-48 min-w-24 break-words"}>{props.row.getValue("name_task")}</span>
        }
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "description_task",
        header: "Description",
        cell: props => {
            return <span className={"break-words block max-w-[32rem]"}>{props.row.getValue("description_task")}</span>
        }
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "due_task",
        header: "Due Date",
        cell: props => {
            return <span className={"block"}>{new Date(props.row.getValue("due_task")).toLocaleString()}</span>
        }
    },{
        header: "Manage",
        cell: () => {
            return <Button>Manage</Button>
        }
    },
]

And this is the component in which I want to import the columns:
const Page: NextPage = async  () => {
    const tasks = await getTasks()
    return (
        <div className={"w-full max-w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center"}>
            <DarkModeToggle/>
            <h1>Tasks</h1>
             <div className={"max-w-[90vw]"}>
                <TaskTable columns={columns} data={tasks}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

I tried removing all of the cell attributes and only use the pure values without any custom html.
This worked, but I need the custom HTML for the cells.

Fixed it.
I forgot to add "use client" to the columns component.
